# How can I automate counting within proofs in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have a function `count` that counts how many times a given predicate is provable when applied to elements of a list. It is defined as follows:

```
Parameter T : Type.

Parameter dec: forall (p: T -> Prop) (w: T), {p w} + {~ (p w)}.

Fixpoint count (p: T -> Prop) (l: list T) := match l with
  | nil => 0
  | (cons head tail) => if (dec p head) then (1 + (count p tail)) else (count p tail)
end.
```

I then use this function to state lemmas like the following:

```
Parameter a b c: T.
Parameter q: T -> Prop.

Axiom Aa: (q a).
Axiom Ab: (q b).
Axiom Ac: ~ (q c).

Lemma example: (count q (cons a (cons b (cons c nil)))) = 2.
```

My proofs of such lemmas tend to be quite tedious:

```
Lemma example: (count q (cons a (cons b (cons c nil)))) = 2.
Proof.
unfold count.
assert (q a); [apply Aa| auto].
assert (q b); [apply Ab| auto].
assert (~ (q c)); [apply Ac| auto].
destruct (dec q a); [auto | contradiction].
destruct (dec q b); [auto | contradiction].
destruct (dec q c); [contradiction | auto].
Qed.
```

What can I do to automate such tedious proofs that involve computation with my `count` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create our custom hint database and add your axioms there:

```
Hint Resolve Aa : axiom_db.
Hint Resolve Ab : axiom_db.
Hint Resolve Ac : axiom_db.
```

Now, the `firstorder` tactic can make use of the hint database:

```
Lemma example: count q (cons a (cons b (cons c nil))) = 2.
Proof.
  unfold count.
  destruct (dec q a), (dec q b), (dec q c); firstorder with axiom_db.
Qed.
```

---

We can automate our solution using the following piece of Ltac:

```
Ltac solve_the_probem :=
  match goal with
  |- context [if dec ?q ?x then _ else _] =>
      destruct (dec q x);
      firstorder with axioms_db;
      solve_the_probem
  end.
```

Then, `unfold count; solve_the_probem.` will be able to prove the lemma.

Comment: Any suggestion about how to do the unfold and the destructs automatically?

Comment: Thanks! The tactic indeed solves the problem, but it is quite slow.

Comment: @Bruno It solves `example` instantly using Coq v8.5pl2. I didn't try it on a larger example though.

Comment: Yes, my real problem is more complicated than the MWE posted in the question. In my real problem `firstorder` needs more time to prove the things that are mere axioms in the MWE.

Answer (score 2):

This is typically the kind of cases where you are better off proving things by reflection. See how things go smoothly (of course I modified a bit your example to avoid all these axioms):

```
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Fixpoint count {T : Type} (p : T -> bool) (l : list T) :=
  match l with
  | [] => 0
  | h :: t => if p h then S (count p t) else (count p t)
  end.

Inductive T := a | b | c.

Definition q x :=
  match x with
  | a => true
  | b => true
  | c => false
  end.

Lemma example: (count q [a; b; c]) = 2.
Proof.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

I realize that your definition of `count` was taking a propositional predicate on type T (but with the assumption that all predicates on type T are decidable) and instead I propose to define `count` to take a boolean predicate. But you may realize that having a decidable propositional predicate or having a boolean predicate is actually equivalent.

E.g. from your axioms, I can define a function which transform any propositional predicate into a boolean one:

```
Parameter T : Type.

Parameter dec: forall (p: T -> Prop) (w: T), {p w} + {~ (p w)}.

Definition prop_to_bool_predicate (p : T -> Prop) (x : T) : bool :=
  if dec p x then true else false.
```

Of course, because there are axioms involved in your example, it won't actually be possible to compute with the boolean predicate. But I'm assuming that you put all these axioms for the purpose of the example and that your actual application doesn't have them.

#### Answer to your comment

As I told you, as soon as you have defined some function in terms of an axiom (or of a [`Parameter`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-specification-language.html#coq:cmdv.parameter) since this is the same thing), there is no way you can compute with it anymore.

However, here is a solution where the decidability of propositional predicate `p` is a lemma instead. I ended the proof of the lemma with [`Defined`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-specification-language.html#coq:cmdv.defined) instead of [`Qed`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-specification-language.html#coq:cmd.qed) to allow computing with it (otherwise, it wouldn't be any better than an axiom). As you can see I also redefined the `count` function to take a predicate and a proof of its decidability. The proof by reflection still works in that case. There is no `bool` but it is strictly equivalent.

```
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Fixpoint count {T : Type}
  (p : T -> Prop) (dec : forall (w: T), {p w} + {~ (p w)}) (l : list T) :=
  match l with
  | [] => 0
  | h :: t => if dec h then S (count p dec t) else (count p dec t)
  end.

Inductive T := a | b | c.

Definition p x := match x with | a => True | b => True | c => False end.

Lemma dec_p: forall (w: T), {p w} + {~ (p w)}.
Proof.
  intros []; simpl; auto.
Defined.

Lemma example2: (count p dec_p [a; b; c]) = 2. Proof. reflexivity. Qed.
```

Comment: I understood the first part of your answer. I agree that, for some applications, this is better way to encode the problem. However, for my application, I really would prefer to stay in Prop (instead of bool) and to have axioms instead of a definition.

Comment: I did not fully understand the second part of your answer. I tried the following:

```Definition p x :=
  match x with
  | a => True
  | b => True
  | c => False
  end.

Parameter dec: forall (p: T -> Prop) (w: T), {p w} + {~ (p w)}.

Definition prop_to_bool (p : T -> Prop) := fun x =>
  if dec p x then true else false.

Lemma example2: (count (prop_to_bool p) [a; b; c]) = 2.
Proof.
  reflexivity.
Qed.```

and Coq complains:

`Error: Unable to unify "2" with
 "count (prop_to_bool p) [a; b; c]".`

Comment: @Bruno see my answer to your comment above.

Comment: I see now. That's nice. The use of `[]` after `intros` is new to me. Could you explain it or point to a tutorial where I could learn more about it? I see that the effect is equivalent to calling `destruct` on the the hypothesis that has just been introduced by `intros`, but I would like understand more deeply the general pattern of using square brackets after `intros`.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed a destructive intro-pattern. The various intro-patterns are documented [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic38). This is not to super easy to read though.

Comment: After seeing your `intros []`, my first reaction was to check Coq's reference manual. But as you said, it is not super-easy to read. That is why I posted that comment, hoping that you could indicate a more digestible tutorial. But thanks anyway!